# Is there a contact number or email chooser/picker for a specific contact?

Tags: android, contacts

I have the contact and I would like the user to choose from his phones or emails. Is that already provided by some picker or shall I implement my own?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                        editTextRecipient.setText(name);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I pass to this my contact, and how do I get the emails out?